# Index xml output of a rest web service into a solr server

Tags: xml, solr

How can i index a solr server with the content of webservice.

my webservice output looks like this
[image]

now i want to index the solr serverwith the content under xml as shown above

how can i index thiss into apache solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a script in your favorite scripting language (Python for me). I did something similar with databases and hope a similar solution will go well fro you.

With Python:

1. urllib2 can fetch the body of your webpage, given the URL.
2. Use an XML parser like etree to recursively descend down the tree, and convert it into an XML/ JSON hierarchy of your choosing (as you prefer)
3. Upload it to Solr (Solr allows uploads in XML, JSON, CSV etc).

And run this script periodically like a cron-job.

---

You will need two pieces of code: one to query your RESTful service and acquire the body of the response; the other to upload a formatted document to Solr.

This piece of code uploads a Python object **request_obj** to the given **request_url** and a solr's response is returned as a Python object. A native Python object (composed of dictionaries (associative arrays), lists, strings, numbers) translates to JSON easily (with 1-2 caveats).

Use this only as reference. I guarantee no suitablity for your purpose.

Dont forget to use **/update/json?wt=python** which is available from Solr 3.3 onwards. You need MultipartPostHandler library.

```
def solr_interface(self,request_url,request_obj):
    request=json.dumps(request_obj,indent=4,encoding="cp1252")
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    req = urllib2.Request(request_url, request)
    req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    text_response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read().strip()
    return ast.literal_eval(text_response)
```

As for parsing (and composing) XML in Python, use these excellent tutorials http://www.learningpython.com/2008/05/07/elegant-xml-parsing-using-the-elementtree-module/ and http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm

This is a commandline sample.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
elem =ET.fromstring("<doc><p>This is a block</p><p>This is another block</p></doc>")
for subelement in elem:
...     print subelement.text
... 
This is a block
This is another block
```

Comment: Updated my answer with some code. And remember, Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loosely follow the steps below to index your data.

1. Configure your Index Schema for the fields you want indexed. Based on the example above, you would want fields for classname, packagename and url. See [SolrSchema](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) for more details.
2. Add the documents to your index. Please see one of the following for details on how you can do this.

   - [Adding documents in XML format](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages)
   - [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_XML.2BAC8-HTTP_Datasource) - Usage with XML/HTTP Datasource